# Por que aplicações em Electron inicializam mais rápido na segunda vez?

Tags: electron

Estou trabalhando agora com o Electron e notei uma coisa bastante interessante. Sempre na primeira vez que eu abro minha aplicação com Electron, demora muito até inicializar a janela. Porém nas próximas vezes não demora nem 1 segundo para carregar. O que está acontecendo?

Comment: Eu vou tentar formular a resposta assim que encontrar algum detalhamento no bugreport, mas o problema do Electron, assim como do Chrome e Opera, é porque isso é uma "falha" do Chromium, sempre teve esse problema, pra iniciar ele é lento, mas quando inicia a primeira vez ele deixa algo semi pronto (que não me recordo se é um cache ou mapeamento) que faz com que as próximas vezes ele inicie rápido, no entanto se fizer logoff ou reiniciar o PC então passa a ocorrer novamente.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ok estou no aguardo.

Answer (score -2):

Eu vou pressupor que você esteja usando o windows.
O computador ao ligar, é como um motorista recém habilitado tentando fazer uma viagem que ele não conhece. Esse motorista FAZ a viagem, mais tem suas dificuldades:
Faz a viagem mais devagar, talvez a 50 ou 60kmh, olha todas as placas, para evitar se perder, Presta atenção em tudo em todos os lugares, mais não decora nada. por fim, ele completa sua viagem de IDA.
Na volta, ele volta mais rápido, já conhece a estrada. Ele tem mais confiança ja não anda mais a 50kmh . Alem disso ele já conhece um pouco da estrada. Suponha que com o passar dos dias ele esteja fazendo muitas viagens pra esse destino como se fosse um motorista de transporte alternativo. em determinado momento em seu trabalho, o motorista que dirigia a 50kmh com medo de se perder, estará dirigindo a 140kmh, praticamente de olhos fechados. Não tem medo de buraco, não tem medo de animais, sabe onde são as lombadas, emfim: SABE TUDO QUE PODE OCORRER DURANTE A VIAGEM. vestígios que sobrou na memoria dele gerou um tipo de mapa mental. e ele agora não tem mais medo. porque virou rotina. agora aquele destino é um esporte pra ele.

No Windows temos o arquivo **Pagefile.sys** ( arquivo de paginação do windows ).
toda vez que você abre um programa a primeira vez, é feito uma varredura nos Slots do seu hd, digamos que LENTAMENTE porque seus arquivos estão fragmentados(quebrado/dividido) em centenas de setores geográficos no hd. isso causa o que chamamos de LENTIDAO NO SISTEMA. na verdade, ele está procurando os pedaços de arquivos que podem estar distantes um do outro. ele copia alguns vestígios(lembranças) da localização desses pedaços de arquivos. na segunda vez que abre, ele já sabe onde estão.
Entretanto, se você abre esse programa muitas vezes... ele vai desfragmentar esse arquivo ( colar as partes, unir , colocar próximos ) e fazer um tipo de compactação e colocar dentro do arquivo **PAGEFILE.SYS** geralmente localizado na unidade " **C:\PAGEFILE.SYS** " Se você aumenta muito a frequência de uso. ele acaba que juntando todos os arquivos. BEM PRÓXIMO UM DO OUTRO. ou seja nesse arquivo **pagefile.sys** e toda vez que você vai abrir o programa, ele abre o arquivo pagefile.sys e lá encontra o seu programa. ele não se sacrifica mais pra abrir.

O pagefile funciona como se fosse uma memoria ram extra. você pode aumentar ou diminuir.
Faça os testes você mesmo:
é um passo a passo longo.
Vá no icone **"Computador"** e clique *com lado direito do mouse*

Clique em ***Propriedades*** ( irá aparecer uma tela com o titulo ***PROPRIEDADES DO SISTEMA*** )

No item ***Desempenho*** clique no `Button`  ***Configurações***

na janela que se abre ( ***Opções de desempenho*** ) clique na aba ***AVANÇADO***

no item ***Memoria virtual***, clique em ***ALTERAR***

na janela que se abre, ( ***memoria virtual*** ) marque o `<radio>` `tamanho personalizado`

Para evitar arquivo fragmentado, nos inputs ***"Tamanho inicial (MB) e Tamanho máximo MB "*** coloque o dobro de sua memoria RAM EM MEGABITS.
por ex:
Se voce tem 2gb de ram ( coloque 4.000 ). se tem 4gb ( 8.000 ). dê ok em tudo.

reinicie o computador. e veja se melhorou o desempenho.
depois teste sem paginação tbm. e por fim, poderá deixar sistema gerenciar.

Leia mais em :
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_mem%C3%B3ria
e
https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/2160852/ram-virtual-memory-pagefile-and-memory-management-in-windows
e
https://canaltech.com.br/windows/o-que-e-e-como-gerenciar-a-memoria-virtual-do-windows/