# Electron criando diversas pastas e arquivos em meu diretório

Tags: electron

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Electron onde eu preciso armazenar alguns dados importantes em um diretório que eu criei em `%APPDATA%`.

O problema é que sempre que eu crio essa pasta (crio utilizando [`fs.mkdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_options)), são criados diversos arquivos e pastas dentro dela de uma só vez. Veja os arquivos que são criados abaixo:

```
AppData/Roaming/myFolder/  <---¬
    myOtherFolder/         <---l-----[Essas duas pastas são as únicas que eu crio]
    blob_storage/
    Cache/
    Code Cache/
    Dictionaries/
    FontLookupTableCache/
    GPUCache/
    Local Storage/
    Session Storage/
    Network Persistent State
    Preferences
```

O que são essas pastas e arquivos criados? Como eu posso impedir isso para que fique apenas as duas pastas que eu criei?

Comment: Essas são pastas do electron não recomendo remover.

Comment: @AnittaDeveloper eu sei que são as pastas do Electron, mas eu quero saber como posso fazer como que elas não sejam criadas no diretório em que eu armazeno os dados? O diretório que eu uso para armazenar os dados não é o mesmo em que eu rodo a aplicação Electron. Tem alguma forma de fazer com que as pastas sejam criadas em um outro local?

Comment: Eu acho que isso não é necessário, porque haveria conflito do electron acha os arquivos.

Comment: @AnittaDeveloper eu realmente preciso dessa pasta limpa apenas com os arquivos que eu mesmo crio. Por favor me ajude com uma solução para resolver este problema.

Comment: Eu não recomendo apaga-las.

Comment: @AnittaDeveloper eu não quero apagar, só quero que elas vão para outro lugar que não seja minha pasta com os dados que desejo, entendeu?

Comment: Resposta editada com detalhes sobre como mudar a localização das pastas do Chromium.

Answer (score 4):

O Electron, como eu já disse antes em um [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/459409/por-que-aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-electron-inicializam-mais-r%C3%A1pido-na-segunda-vez#comment873822_459409), é baseado no [**Chromium**](https://www.chromium.org/), assim como navegadores Chrome, Opera, Bravo, etc.

Então a aplicação criada em HTML+CSS+JS é na verdade uma aplicação hibrida, ou seja, seu programa é um navegador *"disfarçado de programa normal"*, essas pastas são todas usadas pelas tecnologias que tem **nos motores** do Chromium, veja o DevTools:

> [image: aplicativo electron]

Para mudar a localização que terá que usar [`app.setPath(name, path)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetpathname-path) usando o valor de `name` como `userData`:

```
 app.setPath('userData', '/pasta/foo/bar');
```

Sendo `/pasta/foo/bar` a localização novas dessas pastas, claro que é um exemplo. No entanto devo deixar claro que o melhor lugar para manter arquivos temporários é na pasta do usuário, por isso não vejo motivos para mudar, o que você pode fazer se realmente deseja mudar (o que insisto que parece dispensavel) é pegar o valor de `userData` com [**`app.getPath('userData')`**](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname) e aplicar como subpasta:

```
const userData = app.setPath('userData', '/pasta/foo/bar');

app.setPath('userData', `${userData}/chromium`);
```

Eu não testei, mas talvez tenha que criar a pasta manualmente, então se não funcionar execute:

```
var fs = require('fs');

const userData = app.setPath('userData', '/pasta/foo/bar');

try {
    fs.mkdirSync(`${userData}/chromium`);
} catch (ee) {
    if (ee.code !== 'EEXIST') {
        throw e; //Se o erro não for sobre existir então irá emitir um erro e seu programa não irá iniciar
    }
}

app.setPath('userData', `${userData}/chromium`);
```

---

**Nota:** Você pode até apagar, mas os motores **vão gerar novamente** e pode estar certo que tem pastas que ainda não apareceram porque sua aplicação não usou coisas como:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem que provavelmente vai gerar a pasta `File System` (não estou certo, a documentação do chromium é muito complicada)
- Ou se usar videos talvez irá gerar a pasta `VideoDecodeStats`

Não encontrei detalhes de todas pastas, mas aqui vai quase tudo:

- `blob_storage` provavelmente para controle dos blobs gerados como com o uso da API [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) ou `URL.createObjectURL`
- `Cache` contêm cache de requisições HTTP (depende de como configura o seu projeto)
- `Code Cache` essa eu não sei como funciona ao certo, mas parece que são caches de estruturas JS e wasm especificas de alguns sites, não achei fontes
- `Dictionaries` dicionários para corretor ortográfico
- `FontLookupTableCache` - irei editar em breve, parece que é
- `GPUCache` cache usado pelo programa para uso do GPU
- `Local Storage` para uso da API `localStorage`
- `Session Storage` para uso da API sessionStorage
- `Network Persistent State` provavelmente para manter as configurações de persistência referente as requisições HTTP
- `Preferences` todas preferencias configuradas do navegador/programa

Resumindo é somente para controle do próprio navegador embarcado, você mesmo não vai usa-las totalmente, vai só usar "indiretamente"

Comment: Guilherme se eles são apenas arquivos temporários, por que eles não somem e por que eles não ficam na pasta **TEMP**?

Comment: Ei Guilherme, eu testei este método e realmente retirou quase todas as pastas do meu diretório. O problema é que a pasta `Dictionaries` ainda é criada lá. O que eu faço quanto a isso? Eu quero meu diretório clear sem nenhuma dessas pastas do Chromium.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 não, a pasta temp geralmente pode ser limpa por diversos programas, o que pode implicar em problemas no sistema do seu programa, é melhor que o proprio programa gerencie os caches.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 vou ver sobre o Dictionaries, mas devo ressaltar novamente, não é necessário se preocupar com mudar as pastas, você pode fazer, mas é mais perfumaria ... ps: vou pesquisar sobre o Dictionaries

Comment: Guilherme, você conseguiu descobrir sobre essa pasta Dictionaries? Sabe como removê-la?